# intersection between two maps in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have hash-maps and I'm trying to get the intersection between the keys. But the function 'intersection' just work with sets.

So I'm getting the keys, transforming the keys to sets and then calling the intersection, something like this:

```
(intersection (set (keys map-1)) (set (keys map-2)))
```

There are a better way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: That is idiomatic Clojure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be the most straightforward / concise way to do it, and it doesn't require building any sets (which is relatively expensive).

```
(keys (select-keys map-1 (keys map-2)))
```

Finally, an optimized version, which is a bit faster, and a bit harder to read:

```
(keep #(some->> % (find map-1) key) (keys map-2))
```

Comment: A couple of things. 1) The question alludes to `intersection`, which returns a set. Both your solutions return sequences. 2) IMO, `keys` should return a `clojure.lang.MapKeys`, a map disguised as a set by ignoring its values. It doesn't exist. I should write it.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot. There is a way to do the inverse? Instead of the intersection, get the difference?

I tried with the "difference" function, but it still need a set as first argument.

`(difference (set (keys map-2)) (keys map-1))`

Comment: `(keys (apply dissoc map-1 (keys map-2)))` should do the trick

Comment: that will work best if map-1 has fewer keys than map-2 (if by any chance you can determine that beforehand, that's a potential optimization)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is clear and concise.

If performance is a concern, you can avoid constructing the intermediate sets by imitating the structure of [clojure.set/intersection](http://conj.io/store/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clojure.set/intersection/):

```
(defn key-intersection [s1 s2]
  (if (< (count s2) (count s1))
    (recur s2 s1)
    (reduce
     (fn [result item]
       (if (contains? s2 item)
         (conj result item)
         result))
     #{}
     (keys s1))))
```

Comment: since we both mention performance, criterium says my version as of this comment is marginally faster than yours for 10 and 1000 element maps, and marginally slower for 100 element maps. Both are ~3x faster than the original listed.

Comment: 10 elements: 11.5 / 2.78 / 3.15; 100 elements: 117 / 27.3 / 27.0; 1000 elements 1540 / 301 / 315

Comment: with my optimized version, I get 2.81; 26.8; 285

Comment: @noisesmith Interesting. I'm surprised the disparity isn't greater, since I'm using `reduce` under the hood where your first version uses a loop. I've left a couple of comments on your answer:  I liked it better than mine, and voted for it :).

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for arbitrary numbers of maps

```
(defn key-intersection [m & ms]
  (reduce #(keys (select-keys %2 %1)) (keys m) ms))
```

or

```
(defn key-intersection [m & ms]
  (reduce (fn [v c] (keep #(some->> % (find c) key) v)) (keys m) ms))
```